# Reverse an array with React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

Using javascript is there any quick way to swap 2 items in an array?

So if it was a boolean you could do

```
const [isTrue, setIsTrue] = useState(false);

setIsTrue(!isTrue);
```

but say I have an array

```
// I want to swap the items in the array on a click 
const [trueOrFalse, setTrueOrFalse] = useState([true, false]);
```

and I want to switch these, is there a quick way of swapping the items in the array if there are two items

```
setTrueOrFalse(!trueOrFalse); // would equal [false, true]

<div onClick={() => setTrueOrFalse()} />Swap items in array</div>
```

I am trying to take the element at index 0 and move it to index 1, and vice versa.

Comment: I don't get your question.....please clarify

Comment: Are you trying to invert the value of every element in the array? If so, that's just `trueOfFalse.map(val => !val)`. Or are you trying to take the element at index 0 and move it to index 1, and vice versa?

Comment: have updated my question @messerbill is it clearer now?

Comment: @NicholasTower I am trying to take the element at index 0 and move it to index 1, and vice versa

Comment: I think you're supposed to use `useEffect`, as per https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use de-structuring with useState setter callback method

```
// I want to swap the items in the array on a click 
const [trueOrFalse, setTrueOrFalse] = useState([true, false]);

const swapState = () => {
    setTrueOrFalse(prevState => {
        const [val1, val2] = prevState;
        return [val2, val1];
    })
}

<div onClick={() => swapState()} />Swap items in array</div>
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lp8yn4jm8z)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```js
let a=[true, false];

// inverse values
let b= a.map(x=>!x)

// swap sequence (inplace)
a.reverse();

console.log('inverse values', b);
console.log('swap sequence', a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES6 [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Swapping_variables) to easily swap variables in a single expression:

```js
//Get inital array from useState and store in 2 variables
var [val1, val2] = useState();

//Check out the values
console.log(`Before swap values: val1 = ${val1}, val2 = ${val2}`);

//Do the swap using array desctructuring:
[val1, val2] = [val2, val1];

//Now see that the values have swapped
console.log(`After swap values: val1 = ${val1}, val2 = ${val2}`);

function useState() {
  return [true, false];
}
```

Comment: You could reverse the array, sure, but if you're always going to be dealing with an array containing 2 elements then I think this simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can user [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method of array

```js
function reverse(a){
  return a.reverse()
}

console.log(reverse([true, false]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
Array.prototype.swap = function(index1,index2){
 [this[index1], this[index2]] = [this[index2],this[index1]]
}
let arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr.swap(1,2);
console.log(arr);
```